# /bin/sh: 1: composer: not found

Tags: docker, composer-php, laravel-9

I am trying to run a laravel app from a docker container.
Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /app/api
COPY . .

RUN chmod 777 -R storage

RUN composer install
RUN php artisan key:generate

EXPOSE 8000

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

However, when I am running `docker-compose up --build` command. I am getting this error.

```
> [laravel-react-dockerized-backend 8/9] RUN composer install:
#0 0.321 /bin/sh: 1: composer: not found
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: Add "ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" after the curl instruction, or before the compose install step!

Comment: `RUN chmod 777 -R storage`  is likely showing a problem you have with file modes. Executable bits are normally not required for file storage. Take care, only something works must not mean its working towards your behalf. Consider to apply the principle of least privilege.

Comment: _"What could be the solution?"_ - What did you try? How do you understand the problem? Or first of all: What do _you_ read out of the error message? Please share and [edit] in all the information so that it becomes a more answerable question.

Comment: Have you tried: `RUN php /usr/local/bin/composer install`  (invoke php with the full path to the composer phar file instead of just `composer` / `RUN composer install`)? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Get Composer from its [official Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) image with:

```
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

or more safely with a set version:

```
COPY --from=composer:2.5.1 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: While this could be an approach I'm asking myself if it would suffice in the context of this question: From the Dockerfile given, it appears that `/usr/local/bin/composer`  is already there by the installer from `RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer` line. That `RUN`  line _could_ be replaced with the suggested `COPY --from=composer...`  line but does it make a difference?